# php regular expressions documantation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to learn regular expression patterns. I'm using some patterns but there I don't understand things, look below example patterns

```
"%(<$tag.*?>)(.*?)(<\/$tag.*?>)%is"

'/<img class="icerik" src="(.*)" alt="(.*)" \/>/Ui'

'@\b\d+\b@'
```

As you can see:

- some patterns starting and ending with % character,
- some patterns starting and ending with @ character
- some patterns starting and ending with # character,
- also there is 'is,Ui,Xi,i' etc. characters end of patterns.

What is that??  And how I will know, I need which starting and ending character?

Is there any documentation which explains all this?

Comment: google php regular expression tutorials. This seems a good site (video tut) : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/regular-expressions-for-dummies-screencast-series/

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2):

A good resource to learn more on PCRE regular expressions is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).
To answer your question: a regex needs to be delimited by certain chars. Common chars are `#`, `@`, or `/`. But `{expression}` is valid, too.

The reason why you might not use `/`, like a JS regex is that it requires you to escape any forward slashes that are part of your regex

```
/http:\/\/www/i
//can be written as:
#http://www#i
```

the *flags* (as they are called) like in my examples `i` are modifiers that can change the behaviour of the whole pattern: (again `i` is for case-Insensitive):

```
/[a-zA-Z]/
//can be written as
/[a-z]/i
```

[A full list of modifiers can be found in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: +1 and the [link to the PHP Delimiters documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Answer (score 0):

[Gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is a great regular expression learning tool. On the right-most part of your window you can find **samples** tab, there you can understand which expression does what.

*Don't miss this tool !*